# Can I create more than one bitmaps for compatible DC?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Is it right to create two bitmaps for one DC?

My situation is I have

```
 dc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL); 
 bitmap = CreateDIBSection(dc, pbmi1, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **) &bmpBits, NULL, 0);
 extra_bitmap = CreateDIBSection(dc, pbmi2, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **) &extraBmpBits, NULL, 0);
```

The difference is: bitmap is width*height , extra_bitmap is width/2*height*2

I need to show both images on the screen according to requirements from users.

I tried these code above, it can run (based only on my limited test).  But I am not sure if it is the right way to do it. Any suggestions and/or comments are welcome. Thanks.

By the way, if I can have two bitmaps associated with one DC, what is the right way to release them? Can I just call DeleteDC(dc)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Bitmaps are only associated with a DC when they're selected into them via `SelectObject`. The DC you pass to the `CreateDIBSection` is only used to define the layout/palette of the newly created bitmap, and only in some circumstances, but it doesn't irrevocably associate that bitmap with the DC or anything like that.

To draw a bitmap to a window, it needs to be selected into a DC (the "source DC"), and this is where you can only have one at a time.

For example:

```
HDC hdcTarget = GetDC(hWnd); // or hdcTarget = BeginPaint(...)
HDC hdcSource = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcTarget); // create a "source DC")
HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(dc, bitmap); // select bitmap 1 in
BitBlt(hdcTarget, x, y, w, h, hdcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); // draw bitmap 1
SelectObject(hdcSource, extra_bitmap); // select bitmap 2 in
BitBlt(hdcTarget, x1, y1, w1, h1, hdcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); // draw bitmap 2
SelectObject(hdcSource, hOldBmp); // restore previous bitmap
DeleteDC(hdcSource); // no longer needed
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcTarget); // or EndPaint(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. one more question: Do I need to call DeleteObject(bitmap)?

Comment: Eventually, when you've finished using it, you do. It would make sense to create them at the start of your program and delete them at the end rather than every paint cycle though.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Silly question: I create child control, which create compatible dc and compatible bitmap in the WM_CREATE and destroy it in WM_DESTROY. But if resize control bitmap dimension are wrong, because are taken from child window rect in WM_CREATE. Now I delete/create compatible DC/bitmap in WM_SIZE handler, but this method is nearly same as creating/destroying in WM_PAINT. Any recomedation where to create compatible DC/bitmap ?

Comment: `WM_SIZE` is the right place for that I think. You'll get far more `WM_PAINT` messages than you will `WM_SIZE` messages. Alternatively you could check the size in `WM_PAINT` and if it's changed, destroy and recreate it (once) at that point.

Answer (score 0):

After search around for a few hours, I get

http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_MFC_Samples/CreateDIBSection-BITMAPINFOHEADER-CreateCompatibleDC-BITMAPINFO.htm

In this example:

```
// Create HDCs to hold our surfaces.
hdcSrc1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDest);
if (!hdcSrc1) goto HANDLEERROR;

hdcSrc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDest);
if (!hdcSrc2) goto HANDLEERROR;
```

For delete:

```
  DeleteDC(hdcSrc1);
  DeleteDC(hdcSrc2);
  DeleteObject(hbmSrc1);  // hbmSrc1 and hbmSrc2 are created using  hbm = CreateDIBSection(hDC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void **)&pBits, NULL, 0);
  DeleteObject(hbmSrc2);
```

Hope this can be helpful for others. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may create as many in-memory bitmaps as you like.

You may create as many device-dependent DCs as you like.

A bitmap may be selected into only one DC at a time.  If you try to select the same bitmap into multiple DCs, then you will get unpredictable behavior.

A DC will never have more that one bitmap selected into it at a time, because the act of selecting one in selects the previous one out.

Don't delete a memory DC while your bitmap is still selected into it.  You should select the original bitmap (which is a monochrome 1x1 bitmap) into the DC to get your bitmap out before you delete the DC.

Don't delete an in-memory bitmap while it's still selected into a DC.